# Anidar combobox

Tags: java, combobox

necesito anidar dos combobox con un mismo arraylist
la idea es sacar un combobox con el listado de las especialidades de los doctores y otro combobox anidado con la idea de que al seleccionar el combobox de las especialidades me muestre en el combobox de los doctores aquellos que tienen esa especialidad.

el metodo para que no se repitan las especialidades ya esta configurado, a no ser que haya que hacerlo de otra manera

Hola, necesito anidar dos combobox con un mismo arraylist
la idea es sacar un combobox con el listado de las especialidades de los doctores y otro combobox anidado con la idea de que al seleccionar el combobox de las especialidades me muestre en el combobox de los doctores aquellos que tienen esa especialidad.

el metodo para que no se repitan las especialidades ya esta configurado, a no ser que haya que hacerlo de otra manera

```
public class Ejerciciocombo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList<Doctor> listadoctores;

public Ejerciciocombo() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setTitle("prueba de combo");
    iniciarDoctores();
    //MostrarDoctores();
    cargarEspecialidad();

}

public void iniciarDoctores() {

    int i;
    int[] codigo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    String[] nombredoctor = {"Elena Diaz Lopez", "Juan Ruiz Luque", "Marta Jaén García", "Ana Perez Martin", "José Guerrero Castro"};
    String[] especialidad = {"Medicina General", "Medicina General", "Pediatria", "Pediatria", "Cirugia"};
    int[] numconsulta = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5};

    Doctor nuevoDoctor;

    listadoctores = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
    for (i = 0; i < codigo.length; i++) {

        nuevoDoctor = new Doctor(codigo[i], especialidad[i], nombredoctor[i], numconsulta[i]);

        listadoctores.add(nuevoDoctor);

    }

}

public void MostrarDoctores() {
    int i;
    String nombredoctor;
    for (i = 0; i < listadoctores.size(); i++) {

        nombredoctor = listadoctores.get(i).getNombredoctor();
        cmbCombo2.addItem(nombredoctor);

    }

}


public void cargarEspecialidad(){

    Set<String> especialidadRepetida = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <listadoctores.size(); i++){
    especialidadRepetida.add(listadoctores.get(i).getEspecialidad());

    }
    for (String Especialidad : especialidadRepetida){

    cmbCombo1.addItem(Especialidad);




    }

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    cmbCombo1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    cmbCombo2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addComponent(cmbCombo1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(cmbCombo2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(30, 30, 30))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(cmbCombo1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(cmbCombo2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(226, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejerciciocombo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejerciciocombo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejerciciocombo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejerciciocombo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Ejerciciocombo().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbCombo1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbCombo2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tu clase Doctor es algo así:

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question305943;

class Doctor {
    
    int codigo;
    String nombreDoctor;
    String especialidad;
    int numconsulta;

    public Doctor(int codigo, String especialidad, String nombreDoctor, int numconsulta) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombreDoctor = nombreDoctor;
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
        this.numconsulta = numconsulta;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombreDoctor() {
        return nombreDoctor;
    }

    public void setNombreDoctor(String nombreDoctor) {
        this.nombreDoctor = nombreDoctor;
    }

    public String getEspecialidad() {
        return especialidad;
    }

    public void setEspecialidad(String especialidad) {
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
    }

    public int getNumconsulta() {
        return numconsulta;
    }

    public void setNumconsulta(int numconsulta) {
        this.numconsulta = numconsulta;
    }    
}
```

Yo primeramente dejaría vacío el combo de doctores para que se notara más el flujo de la funcionalidad, es decir sin inicializar.

Para el combo de especialidades le agregaría una opción de `Todas` para que saque a cualquier especialidad y usar ese valor como Centinela.

Ahora en las fases, antes del pack de la interfaz gráfica haría las llamadas de inicialización para que la redimensión sea acorde a los datos.

```
iniciarDoctores();
cargarEspecialidad();
pack();
```

Y el escucha de eventos, realmente no importa si lo pones antes o después, ya que no es un elemento visual, pero igual lo pondría inmediatamente después del pack, esto porque no es realmente parte de la construcción, sino de la configuración gráfica.

Yo haría un `ItemListener`, para asegurarme que atrape el evento de cambio de elemento seleccionado mediante el evento

```
ItemEvent.SELECTED
```

Es decir, yo lo haría algo así:

```
cmbCombo1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                String especialdd = (String) e.getItem();
                System.out.println("especialidad:" + especialdd);
                filtraDoctoresPorEspecialidad(especialdd);
            }
        }
    });
```

Ahora cmo verás la funcionalidad de filtrado la pondría en otro método. ¿Por qué? Por el primer principio de SOLID, conocido en castellano como separación de responsabilidades.

El evento del escucha se encarga de la lógica relacionada con los eventos, y un método aparte se encarga de la lógica relacionada al filtrado para prevenir confusiones o que la lógica se mezcle por querer optimizar el código.

En esta función reusamos tu lógica básica que ya tenías y le agregamos condiciones de pintado con los siguiente criterios:

Si es la opción `Todas` deberá de mostrar a todos los doctores sin importar nada más.

Si la opción es un nombre de especialidad, deberá de agregar a la lista que va a mostrar únicamente a aquellos que tengan esa especialidad.

Para asegurarnos de que no haya duplicados ni algún problema borraremos los doctores mediante el método `removeAllItems()`.

```
private void filtraDoctoresPorEspecialidad(String especialidad) {
        cmbCombo2.removeAllItems();
        int i;
        String nombredoctor;
        for (i = 0; i < listadoctores.size(); i++) {
            Doctor doctor = listadoctores.get(i);
            nombredoctor = doctor.getNombreDoctor();
            if (especialidad.equalsIgnoreCase("Todas")||doctor.getEspecialidad().equalsIgnoreCase(especialidad)) {
                cmbCombo2.addItem(nombredoctor);
            }

        }
    }
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question305943;

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Ejerciciocombo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList<Doctor> listadoctores;

    public Ejerciciocombo() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle("prueba de combo");

    }

    public void iniciarDoctores() {

        int i;
        int[] codigo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        String[] nombredoctor = {"Elena Diaz Lopez", "Juan Ruiz Luque", "Marta Jaén García", "Ana Perez Martin", "José Guerrero Castro"};
        String[] especialidad = {"Medicina General", "Medicina General", "Pediatria", "Pediatria", "Cirugia"};
        int[] numconsulta = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5};

        Doctor nuevoDoctor;

        listadoctores = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
        for (i = 0; i < codigo.length; i++) {

            nuevoDoctor = new Doctor(codigo[i], especialidad[i], nombredoctor[i], numconsulta[i]);

            listadoctores.add(nuevoDoctor);

        }

    }

    public void cargarEspecialidad() {

        Set<String> especialidadRepetida = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listadoctores.size(); i++) {
            Doctor doctor = listadoctores.get(i);
            especialidadRepetida.add(doctor.getEspecialidad());
        }
        cmbCombo1.addItem("Todas");
        for (String Especialidad : especialidadRepetida) {
            cmbCombo1.addItem(Especialidad);
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        cmbCombo1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        cmbCombo2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                                .addComponent(cmbCombo1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(cmbCombo2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(30, 30, 30))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(cmbCombo1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(cmbCombo2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addContainerGap(226, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addContainerGap())
        );

        iniciarDoctores();
        cargarEspecialidad();

        pack();

        cmbCombo1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    String especialdd = (String) e.getItem();
                    System.out.println("especialidad:" + especialdd);
                    filtraDoctoresPorEspecialidad(especialdd);
                }
            }
        });
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void filtraDoctoresPorEspecialidad(String especialidad) {
        cmbCombo2.removeAllItems();
        int i;
        String nombredoctor;
        for (i = 0; i < listadoctores.size(); i++) {
            Doctor doctor = listadoctores.get(i);
            nombredoctor = doctor.getNombreDoctor();
            if (especialidad.equalsIgnoreCase("Todas")||doctor.getEspecialidad().equalsIgnoreCase(especialidad)) {
                cmbCombo2.addItem(nombredoctor);
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejerciciocombo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejerciciocombo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejerciciocombo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejerciciocombo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Ejerciciocombo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbCombo1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbCombo2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration  
}
```

Si por alguna razón ocupas que se pinten los doctores como estado inicial solo debes agregarle la llamada a `filtraDoctoresPorEspecialidad(especialdd);` antes de que hagas visible el formulario.

### Capturas

Inicial
[image: estado inicial]

Filtrado por especialidad

[image: Filtrado con un solo resultado]

[image: filtrado con más de un resultado]

Sin filtrar

[image: Filtrar por todas las especialidades]